# Pass data from containerView to MainViewControler

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
MainViewControler:
class MainViewControler: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster {
    @IBOutlet weak var systemContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteProductBtn2: UIButton!
    weak var containerViewController: Calculator1ViewController?

    func changeBtn() {
        favoriteProductBtn2.isHidden = true
        print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    }
}


CallculatorViewController:
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

class CallculatorViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}


Calculator1ViewController:
protocol ContainerToMaster {
    func changeBtn()
}

class Calculator1ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerToMaster?.changeBtn()
    }
}
```

I have such an application layout:

1. Main view = `MainViewControler`.
   In `MainViewControler`, I have a containerView (systemContainerView) in which the `MainViewControler` is located
2. In the `CallculatorViewController`, I have the next containerView in which the `Calculator1ViewController` is located.

When entering the `Calculator1ViewController` the function: `containerToMaster?.changeBtn()` should start (it should work in `MainViewControler`).

The problem is - this function does not work :(

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Tip : declare your containerViewController as weak var

Comment: ok, I changed. but nothing helped :(

Comment: your `containerToMaster ` object is nil if I'm not mistaken ... maybe set ..`containerViewController.containerToMaster  = self`

Comment: where to add it?

Comment: I usually pass data from container view controller to its parent using. 
`if let parent = self.parent as? ProductDetailVc { parent.passData(dataToPass:String) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contained viewController is embedded with an *embed segue*.  You need to override `prepare(for:sender)` and set `self` as the `containerToMaster` delegate in the destination viewController.  Your situation is complicated by the fact that you have a container view embedded in another container view, so you'll need to set up two delegates and pass the button call back:

```
protocol ContainerToMaster {
    func changeBtn()
}


class MainViewControler: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster {
    @IBOutlet weak var systemContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteProductBtn2: UIButton!
    weak var containerViewController: Calculator1ViewController?

    func changeBtn() {
        favoriteProductBtn2.isHidden = true
        print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? CallculatorViewController {
            destVC.containerToMaster = self
        }
    }
}

class CallculatorViewController: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster {
    weak var containerToMaster: ContainerToMaster?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func changeBtn() {
        // pass the button call back
        containerToMaster?.changeBtn()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? Calculator1ViewController {
            destVC.containerToMaster = self
        }
    }
}

class Calculator1ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var containerToMaster: ContainerToMaster?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerToMaster?.changeBtn()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated the answer.  I realized you had a container view embedded within a second container view.  That requires 2 levels of setup.

Comment: Do some debugging.  Put prints in each of the prepare functions.  Are the delegates assigned?  Do either of the changeBtn functions get called?

Comment: Do I have the right understanding that CalculatorViewController is embedded in Main, and Calculator1ViewController is embedded in CallculatorViewController?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)